# VBA empty rows getting filled after running code

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on a code to filter different columns and depending on some characteristics to change it changes the value and highlights it. However, I noticed that it also adds values at the end of my dataset, and I don't know why it is doing so.

[image: Dataset after running code]

```
Sub Delivery_Time()


Dim rg As Range
Dim FilterP, Filter1, Filter6 As Variant


' For ZSFG (Syrup) need to be 'Blank'
'For ZCNC should not be blank
 Set rg = Worksheets("MARC").Range("A2").CurrentRegion


 Filter1 = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="MATERIAL TYPE", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
 Filter6 = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Planned Deliv. Time", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
 FilterP = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Procurement Type", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

 With rg
  .AutoFilter Field:=Filter1, Criteria1:="ZSFG", Operator:=xlFilterValues
  .AutoFilter Field:=Filter6, Criteria1:="1", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="2"

  With .Columns(Filter6).Offset(2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
    With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Clear
        With .Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
  End With
End With

 With rg
   .AutoFilter Field:=Filter1, Criteria1:="ZCNC", Operator:=xlFilterValues
   .AutoFilter Field:=Filter6, Criteria1:="=", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="0"

    With .Columns(Filter6).Offset(2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
       With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
          .Value = ""
          With .Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
          End With
      End With
  End With
 .Parent.ShowAllData



  End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: Your code contains only two lines (.Value = "", .Clear) aimed at changing cell values. However, neither of them assigns values to cells. It seems you must have additional code to `add values`. btw, if the table header is on row 1 (without merged cells), it should be `.Columns(Filter6).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)` [Offset one row]

Comment: if I do this, I get an error message that says "No cells were found"

Comment: It indicates that there are no rows that satisfy the filtering criteria. You need to add code to validate whether `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` is nothing or not.

Comment: I've posted an answer to show how to prevent the error. But I still don't know about `add values` without further clarification from OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To prevent a runtime error, make sure to check the return value of `SpecialCells` before proceeding with the next steps.

```vb
    With rg
        .AutoFilter Field:=Filter1, Criteria1:="ZSFG", Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .AutoFilter Field:=Filter6, Criteria1:="1", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="2"
        
        With .Columns(Filter6).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
            Dim visRng As Range
            Set visRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            If Not visRng Is Nothing Then
                With visRng
                    .Clear
                    With .Interior
                        .Pattern = xlSolid
                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .Color = 65535
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                    End With
                End With
            End If
        End With
    End With
```